# iScroll not working on iPhone for jquery show/hide

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, iscroll

I am building a phonegap application with iscroll used for scrolling. I am facing a problem when I dynamically append controls to a div and show/hide the div on click. The div shows up and then hides automatically. I have given the code samples below. Would greatly apperciate any help.

First I tried with scroll.refresh() alone, but since it did not work, I tried destroying and recreating according to a forum post in google. But, it does not work either.

## HTML

```
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
        <main class="content" id="scroller">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span id="usertype-link">
                    </span>
                    <div class="b-preferences__select b-preferences__select--type" id="search-user-type-div">
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </main>
    </div>
```

## JS

```
$('#search-user-type-div').hide();
$('#usertype-link').bind('click', function () {
    if ($('#search-user-type-div').is(":visible")) {
        $('#search-user-type-div').hide();
        $('#usertype-link').removeClass('open').addClass('close');
    }
    else {
        $('#search-user-type-div').show();
        $('#usertype-link').removeClass('close').addClass('open');
    }
    //scroll.refresh();
    searchpreferences.rebuildScroll();
})

rebuildScroll: function () {
    scroll.destroy();
    scroll = null;
    scroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { vScrollbar: true, hScrollbar: false, vScroll: true, hScroll: false, onBeforeScrollStart: null });

    //setTimeout(function () {
    scroll.refresh();
    //}, 0);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Priyan

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact solution, but I recommend to use the most recent version of [iScroll (v5)](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll). It was totally rebuild and maybe fixes your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried moving from iscroll 4 to 5 but issue is not fixed. Infact now nothing happens. I am doing some more tests will comment if succeed.